# insert select alias value into column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

Not sure if this is the best title, but i want to select string values into an int column of a new table (the reason is to use keys with int data types rather than strings, so there are more columns not shown in this example)

```
table1.key1   table2.key2
a                1
b                2
c                3
a                1
```

one way i can do this is as follows but the syntax is very very long in some scenarios

```
insert into  table2 (key2)
select 1
from table1
where key1 = 'a'

insert into table2 (key2)
select 2
from table1
where key1 ='b'
```

etc...

can someone show me how i could use a syntax that is shorter? also i have to keep identity insert set to off so an update statement will not work from what i understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d839a/1)**

Use a `CASE` expresion

```
insert into  table2 (key2)
select CASE WHEN key1 = 'a' THEN 1
            WHEN key1 = 'b' THEN 2
            WHEN key1 = 'c' THEN 3
            .....
            ELSE -1
       END as key2
from table1
```